# using php to provide a variable in an onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, onclick

I am trying to pass a variable through the onclick function into javascript.

So I am trying to pass

```
onclick = "purchase_song(<?php echo $row['filename']; ?> , <?php echo $row['price'] ?> )"
```

note the function works fine if I pass it a non php variable

```
onclick = "purchase_song( 'filename'  , 1)"
```

And I use a similar technique to pass variables through hyperlinks and the GET function.  Is it not possible to use PHP inside a javascript onlick?  If so, what am I doing wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: PHP runs on the server. The HTML in the browser should look the same. Just view the page source in the browser and the difference between the static (non php) and the dynamic (php) version should be obvious.

Comment: Have a look at the **generated** code. It should be clear from that what the problem is. Also, [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820).

Comment: Thanks, I had actually tried that but thought I had to put it in as &lsque;  etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the values are valid strings then you are doing everything right except one thing : to pass php input as a string argument to the javascript function you should wrap it in single quotes `'`:

```
onclick = "purchase_song('<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>' , '<?php echo $row['price'] ?>')"
```

Comment: Thanks, I had actually tried that but thought I had to put it in as &lsque;  etc

Answer (score 0):

The values should need to be quoted.

```
onclick="<?php printf("purchase_song('%s', '%s')", $row['filename'], $row['price'] ?>"
```

This example uses [printf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) as its easer to see what the output from the format string.